# How to Right Scroll Using Ruby Watir?

Tags: ruby, testing, watir

How to right scroll using Ruby Watir?

When I tried to click on the slide bar to move to right

it is not working

Comment: Are you trying to scroll the webpage? Or table inside the webpage?

Comment: It would help to provide the HTML/JavaScript/CSS that reproduces the problem as well as the Watir code you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really good question, this should work

`@b.execute_script('$("#your_element_id").scrollLeft("10000")')`

Or send exact number (instead 10000) if you can read the width prior. Post html structure next time :)

Answer (score 1):

Watir has a scrolling library that can be used instead of execute_script:

```
horizontal_offset = 10000
vertical_offset = 0
browser.scroll.by(horizontal_offset, vertical_offset)
```

or if you need to bring an element into the viewport:

```
browser.element(id: 'my-element').scroll.to(:center)
```